# How do I index XML data within a content node?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-explorer

I'm converting an XML document and want to dump the entire contents in a content node in the converter.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <vce>
    <document>
      <content name="xml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </content>
    </document>
  </vce>
</xsl:template>
```

This gives me a node with the name "XML" and my entire xml content within. However, this is removed when the normalization converter is run. Is there something special I need to do to index XML inside a content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reference the converter: 'vse-converter-xml-to-vxml' to create a template that indexes the xml:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

  <vce>
    <document>
      <content name="xml">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="xml-to-plain-text" />
      </content>
    </document>
  </vce>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="xml-to-plain-text">
  <xsl:text><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="text()|*|comment()">
      <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text()|*|comment()" mode="xml-to-plain-text" />
      <xsl:text><![CDATA[</]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
      <xsl:text>></xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:text>/></xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```